# I want to compile with clang/clang++ by detecting clang with the correct procedure with cmake

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cmake, clang, llvm

Below is what I want to do.

I want to compile with clang/clang++ by detecting clang with the correct procedure with cmake.

Please tell me the correct procedure that I can solve the problems I will describe.

> ```
> test environment:
> OS   : Ubuntu 16.10 64bit
> gcc  : gcc (Ubuntu 6.2.0-5ubuntu12) 6.2.0 20161005
> clang: 6.0.0 (self build)
> cmake: 3.11.3
> ```

I did the following procedure, but it can not be detected correctly.

I just described the detected portion of CMakeLists.txt.

CMakeLists.txt

```
function(display_vars vars prefix)
  message("${prefix}")
  foreach(IT ${vars})
    message("${prefix}${IT} = ${${IT}}")
  endforeach()
endfunction()


include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)

set(project_name clang-test)

project(${project_name})

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)

include_directories( ${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_definitions ( ${LLVM_DEFINITIONS} )

enable_language(CXX)

# setup compile & link flags
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++17 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++1z COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++14 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++1y COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++11 COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
check_cxx_compiler_flag(-std=c++0x COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)

# setup compile & link flags
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1z")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++14")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++1y")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
  message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler has no C++11 support.")
endif()


set(echo_vars)
# result by find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG) 
list(APPEND echo_vars LLVM_DIR LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS LLVM_DEFINITIONS)
# detect environment
list(APPEND echo_vars 
  CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID 
  CMAKE_C_STANDARD 
  CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID 
  CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD
  CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
  CMAKE_GNUtoMS 
  CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME 
  CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC 
  CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX 
  CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CLANG
  CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW 
  CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN
  CMAKE_GNU_COMPILER_ID 
  CMAKE_CLANG_COMPILER_ID)

display_vars("${echo_vars}" "env: ")


set(project_sources test.cpp)

add_executable(${project_name} ${project_sources})
```

test.cpp

```
#include <string_view>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    return 0;
}


cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ./
```

When this command is executed, only gcc is detected and clang is not detected at all.

```
which clang
> /usr/local/bin
```

This will be detected.

The installation path of clang which made self build is the default /usr/local/.

The detection log is as follows and only GCC is detected.

log

```
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 6.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
env: 
env: LLVM_DIR = /usr/local/lib/cmake/llvm
env: LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION = 6.0.0
env: LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include
env: LLVM_DEFINITIONS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
env: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID = GNU
env: CMAKE_C_STANDARD = 
env: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID = GNU
env: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD = 
env: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++17
env: CMAKE_GNUtoMS = 
env: CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = Linux
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX = 1
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CLANG = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN = 
env: CMAKE_GNU_COMPILER_ID = 
env: CMAKE_CLANG_COMPILER_ID = 
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X - Success
```

There is a message like the following in the log though it is a different story from the main subject.

Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17 - Success

This gcc (6.2.0) only supports c++ 1z.

In gcc it is correct to be as follows.

```
CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++1z
```

I will return the talk to the subject.

Force specify the compiler to use to detect clang.

```
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" ./ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/clang++
```

new log

```
CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 6.0.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/clang++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
env: 
env: LLVM_DIR = /usr/local/lib/cmake/llvm
env: LLVM_PACKAGE_VERSION = 6.0.0
env: LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include
env: LLVM_DEFINITIONS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
env: CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID = Clang
env: CMAKE_C_STANDARD = 
env: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID = Clang
env: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD = 
env: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS = -std=c++17
env: CMAKE_GNUtoMS = 
env: CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME = Linux
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUC = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CLANG = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW = 
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN = 
env: CMAKE_GNU_COMPILER_ID = 
env: CMAKE_CLANG_COMPILER_ID = 
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Z - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX14 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX1Y - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11 - Success
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X
-- Performing Test COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X - Success
```

It is now detected.

```
CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CLANG
CMAKE_CLANG_COMPILER_ID
```

However, the above variables remain empty.

Let's compile a simple file for the time being.

Put the following at the beginning of the source file.

```
#include <string_view>
```

Then the following error occurs.

```
fatal error: 'string_view' file not found
#include <string_view>
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

clang 6.0 supports c++17 and should be compilable.

Try changing include into the following.

This is the path of string_view in c++1z.

```
#include <experimental/string_view>
```

Describing as above will successfully compile.

I thought about what this meant.

The compiler is clang, but the system include path is used by gcc.

It can only be thought that **/usr/include/c++/6.2.0/experimental** is referenced using /usr/include in the system include path.

As my reasoning,

```
-DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/bin/clang++
```

Although the compiler was forcibly specified with the above option, it does not change that the other environment is not correctly detected.

If it is detected correctly, the system include path should use **LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS = /usr/local/include.**

Also, I think that the CMAKE variable will be as follows.

```
env: CMAKE_CLANG_COMPILER_ID = 1
env: CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CLANG = 1
```

It seems to be in trouble simply by forcibly setting this environment setting.

I think that unless cmake correctly recognizes clang, environment variables affecting compilation will not be changed properly.

How can this be possible?

By the way, when we tested in the following environment,

> ```
> OS   : Ubuntu 18.04 64bit
> gcc  : gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0
> clang: 6.0.0 (self build)
> cmake: 3.11.3
> ```

```
#include <string_view>
```

This compilation succeeded.

However, perhaps the system include path used is **/usr/include/**.

Compilation succeeded because gcc has officially corresponded to c++17 and experimental is gone.

I tried the other one.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config c++
```

It only recognizes g++

If a package is installed with apt install clang etc, will something on the system's database be updated?

Because it is a self-build, it may not be recognized.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all these fancy c++1z features, you need not only the compiler that supports it, but also a standard C++ library. Clang picks whatever library it finds and it happens to be GCC's one.

Try installing `libc++` and adding `-stdlib=libc++` flag to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`.